# ios13/Xcode11: searchResultsController of UISearchController no longer modal?

Tags: ios13, xcode11

For my searchResultsController when the searchcontroller is active, I now have a gap between the controller textbox and the searchResultsController VC. Manually setting the searchResultsController VC to full screen doesn't resolve. Anything I'm missing?

Comment: I ended up manually manipulating the UI when the search controller is activated, to resolve the gap issue. iOS seems to have a lot of bugs of which this is probably one.